# Placing turtles at edges of patch clusters

Tags: netlogo

I'm looking for a way to rapidly place turtles at edges of patch clusters. I tried this code but I found that it is a little slow when I increase the size of my study area:

```
to draw-edges [ID-cluster]
ask patches with [cluster != ID-cluster] [ 
ask neighbors with [cluster = ID-cluster] [ 
  if not any? turtles-here [ 
    sprout 1 [ 
      set shape "x" ] ] ] ] 
end
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're currently asking the whole world outside your cluster to check for neighbors that are in the cluster. It should be faster to ask patches that *are* part of your cluster to check if they are next to an outside patch:

```
to draw-edges [ ID-cluster ]
  ask patches with [
    cluster = ID-cluster and
    any? neighbors with [cluster != ID-cluster] and
    not any? turtles-here
  ] [
    sprout 1
    set shape "x"
  ] 
end
```